# Mensagem de sucesso ao terminar upload de imagens

Tags: jquery

Por que na hora que termina o *upload* das imagens não esta entrando no "DONE" quando ele teria que apresentar uma mensagem de sucesso.

Estou usando o *plugin* jQuery File Upload.

Segue meu código:

```
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
    dataType: 'json',
    autoUpload: true,
    acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i,
    maxFileSize: 5000000, // 5 MB
    // Enable image resizing, except for Android and Opera,
    // which actually support image resizing, but fail to
    // send Blob objects via XHR requests:
    disableImageResize: /Android(?!.*Chrome)|Opera/
        .test(window.navigator.userAgent),
    previewMaxWidth: 50,
    previewMaxHeight: 50,
    previewCrop: true

}).on('fileuploadadd', function (e, data) {
    data.context = $('<div class="imgs-upload"><div/>').appendTo('#files');
    $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
        var node = $('<p/>')
                //.append($('<span/>').text(file.name));
        if (!index) {
            node
                .append('<br>')
                //.append(uploadButton.clone(true).data(data));
        }
        node.appendTo(data.context);
    });
}).on('fileuploadprocessalways', function (e, data) {
    var index = data.index,
        file = data.files[index],
        node = $(data.context.children()[index]);
    if (file.preview) {
        node
            .prepend('<br>')
            .prepend(file.preview);
    }
    if (file.error) {
        node
            .append('<br>')
            .append($('<span class="text-danger"/>').text(file.error));
    }
    if (index + 1 === data.files.length) {
        data.context.find('button')
            .text('Upload')
            .prop('disabled', !!data.files.error);
    }
}).on('fileuploadprogressall', function (e, data) {
    var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
    $('#progress .progress-bar').css(
        'width',
        progress + '%'
    );          

}).on('fileuploaddone', function (e, data) {
    $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
        if (file.url) {
            var link = $('<a>')
                .attr('target', '_blank')
                .prop('href', file.url);
            $(data.context.children()[index])
                .wrap(link);
        } else if (file.error) {
            var error = $('<span class="text-danger"/>').text(file.error);
            $(data.context.children()[index])
                .append('<br>')
                .append(error);
        }
    });

}).on('fileuploadfail', function (e, data) {
    $.each(data.files, function (index) {
        var error = $('<span class="text-danger"/>').text('File upload failed.');
        $(data.context.children()[index])
            .append('<br>')
            .append(error);
    });

}).on('done', function (e, data) {
     alert('teste');

}).prop('disabled', !$.support.fileInput)
    .parent().addClass($.support.fileInput ? undefined : 'disabled');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    dataType: 'json',
    autoUpload: true,
    acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i,
    maxFileSize: 5000000, // 5 MB
    // Enable image resizing, except for Android and Opera,
    // which actually support image resizing, but fail to
    // send Blob objects via XHR requests:
    disableImageResize: /Android(?!.*Chrome)|Opera/
        .test(window.navigator.userAgent),
    previewMaxWidth: 50,
    previewMaxHeight: 50,
    previewCrop: true,

    done: function(e,data){
         alert('teste');
    }

}).on('fileuploadadd', function (e, data) {
    data.context = $('<div class="imgs-upload"><div/>').appendTo('#files');
    $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
        var node = $('<p/>')
                //.append($('<span/>').text(file.name));
        if (!index) {
            node
                .append('<br>')
                //.append(uploadButton.clone(true).data(data));
        }
        node.appendTo(data.context);
    });
}).on('fileuploadprocessalways', function (e, data) {
    var index = data.index,
        file = data.files[index],
        node = $(data.context.children()[index]);
    if (file.preview) {
        node
            .prepend('<br>')
            .prepend(file.preview);
    }
    if (file.error) {
        node
            .append('<br>')
            .append($('<span class="text-danger"/>').text(file.error));
    }
    if (index + 1 === data.files.length) {
        data.context.find('button')
            .text('Upload')
            .prop('disabled', !!data.files.error);
    }
}).on('fileuploadprogressall', function (e, data) {
    var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
    $('#progress .progress-bar').css(
        'width',
        progress + '%'
    );          

}).on('fileuploaddone', function (e, data) {
    $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
        if (file.url) {
            var link = $('<a>')
                .attr('target', '_blank')
                .prop('href', file.url);
            $(data.context.children()[index])
                .wrap(link);
        } else if (file.error) {
            var error = $('<span class="text-danger"/>').text(file.error);
            $(data.context.children()[index])
                .append('<br>')
                .append(error);
        }
    });

}).on('fileuploadfail', function (e, data) {
    $.each(data.files, function (index) {
        var error = $('<span class="text-danger"/>').text('File upload failed.');
        $(data.context.children()[index])
            .append('<br>')
            .append(error);
    });

}).prop('disabled', !$.support.fileInput)
    .parent().addClass($.support.fileInput ? undefined : 'disabled');
```

Para maiores informações : https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Basic-plugin
abraço!